# Get text information from TX Text Control 23.0 for WPF

Tags: c++, txtextcontrol

I need to get/set text information (text, position of cursor, rectangle of cursor position, selection) from TX Text Control 23.0 for WPF.

I tried to get text information by Text Service Framework but ITfDocumentMgr have only one context (ITfContext) which have no any useful info about TX Text Control and I can't get text information.

How do you think, how we can get text information from WPF TX Text Control?

Thanks, for any ideas.

Link on WPF Tx Text: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/downloads/trials/index/default/dotnetwpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text using the .text property

```
var intText;
intText = textControl1.Text
```

If you want to get the selected text from the text control then you can use the below code.

```
TXTextControl.Selection mySel = new TXTextControl.Selection(3, 4); 
textControl1.Selection = mySel;
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, but I have no TXTextControl object.

I have my app which want to know properties of TXTextControl which opened in another window.

Comment: I am not able to get what you are saying. Can you be more specific on what you want?

Comment: I have two open apps: 1) Tx Text 23.0; 2) My app which want to get/set selection, text, cursor position into Tx Text 23.0

Comment: Is your app independent and not using txtext 23.0?

Comment: Yes, my app is independent and not using TxText.